# MongoDB gets very slow

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, search

I have a site which searches the website source codes. but when DB, gets more then 100 site, mongodb starts to work slower.

here is my code:

```
$arananlar = $db->kaynaklar->find(array("kaynak" => new MongoRegex("/".$kelime."/siU")))->sort(array("_id" => -1))->limit($kactane)->skip($alt);
```

Comment: Without knowing what's in `$kelime`, its hard to know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to speed up searches is by adding an index. But indexes can't help when you use regular expressions. An index only helps you when you know exactly what you search for. But regular expressions are much more complex than that. They need to read the whole content of each string for a match ([exception: when the regular expression starts with the start-of-string anchor `^`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/)).

But when you don't need the full power of regular expressions and only search for complete words, [you can create a text index and use text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/).

When you want to know if a specific query uses an index or not, you can use the explain method of the cursor.

Comment: I use both user window, and coding window but I removed spaces and make the search in source code which has no redundant word or unnecessary space.

Comment: @Serhat I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your comment has to do with my answer. Please clarify.

Comment: @Serhat when you solved your problem yourself with a method different from my answer, you should write another answer yourself so that others can learn from your experience. Answering your own question is not frowned upon here - it's even encouraged.

Comment: Thank you, your answer, I couldn't remember that how i did solve. Also you right, I should write to answer here. Sorry.